# Import data into mysql using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there anyway I can import only data from one table to another (same structure) in phpmyadmin?
I exported only rows and not table.

But when I import this data I get the error
`table already exist`

Comment: Your backup code probably has a `create table` in it. So edit the file and comment out the create. I am assuming the backup was done to a editable SQL Source format

Comment: thx a lot.. removed create table query and it worked..